# MKMapKit disalow deselection of callout bubble

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, callout

I would like to know how I can make sure that a `callout` bubble can't get deselected on a `MKMapView`.

Whenever I press on the map (background), this view:
[image: With bubble]

Turns to:
[image: Without bubble]

Which I do not want to allow. Yet I do want to keep the `callOutButton` support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just programmatically select your annotation whenever annotations get deselected (using the corresponding delegate method).  If you don't animate this selection then it looks as if the annotation never got deselected in the first place.

Example:

```
// MKMapView Delegate 
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    // Replace "myAnnotation" with whichever annotation you need to remain selected
    [mapView selectAnnotation:self.myAnnotation animated:NO];
}
```

I tried this in a test project and it works fine (it doesn't flicker or anything).  It's not exactly disabling deselection but the resulting effect is the same, so it might be a good workaround.

Comment: Nice one! Should have though of that myself. Thnx.

Comment: No worries, sometimes it just takes a pair of fresh eyes.